# Can I execute a shell script from a web page?

Tags: java, jsp, shell, cron

My web page uploads a file.  Currently it places that file in a directory which is polled by a cron job.  If the file is there, a bash script acts on the file.  I hate the fact that I am polling.  The upload happens perhaps once a week, but the user wants to see results within minutes from their file, so I end up polling every 5 minutes.

So rather than polling, I'd like to evoke the script once the upload is complete.  How can I get my web page to fire up the bash script.  The web page is coded with JSP.

Comment: Just a note that you've got quite the entry point there - make sure you've done a thorough security audit here!

Comment: @LFSR, The upload page is authenticated and within our intranet. It is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

So long as you haven't got a `SecurityManager` set, you can use `Runtime.exec` to call an executable program. In particular you can run `/bin/bash` (or whatever path it is to your shell). Note the `-c` option for shells.

As LFSR points out, this is the sort of thing likely to be full of security flaws.

Comment: java.lang.SecurityManager. Not very fashionable. Mostly used for applets and WebStart.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you do this from your app? It won't be very hard to implement an FTP client in Java. Surely there are open/free libraries to accomplish this somewhere. I don't believe this script does anything that you can't do in Java. A message driven bean with the FTP code should be enough. Your server is not FTP? Well, installing FTP isn't that hard either.

Comment: The script does more than we are willing to write in Java.  Not because Java can't, but one line in bash to do a rsync using a dsa/rsa link would take considerable effort to replicate in Java.